# SQL Server fails to convert text to time when using same column multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like so:

| Row | Time |
| --- | --- |
| First | '06:00-18:00' |
| Second | '08:00-22:00' |

I'm trying to cast the text in `Time` to new columns `Start` and `End` like so:

| Row | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 06:00 | 18:00 |
| Second | 08:00 | 22:00 |

I'm using the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
    Row, 
    CAST(SUBSTRING(Time, 1, 5) AS TIME) AS 'Start',
    CAST(SUBSTRING(Time, 7, 5) AS TIME) AS 'End'
FROM
    Table
```

When I have one `CAST(SUBSTRING(Time...` in the `Select`, it works as expected.

But when I have 2 `CAST(SUBSTRING(Time...`'s in, I keep getting the error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Is there a reason why it would fail to convert?

Comment: its not because of that  , you have a string that is not able to be converted to time , look into your data in the Time column . look

Comment: You are correct. Turns out I had a 24:00 in there unable to convert.

Answer (score 0):

I think symbol ( **'** ) is your main problem. By changing `SUBSTRING` start index you can achieve your desire output. Please check my query and let me know.

```
DECLARE @MYTable TABLE
(
ROWName VARCHAR(10),
ROWTime VARCHAR(120)
);
INSERT INTO @MYTable VALUES('First','''06:00-18:00''');
INSERT INTO @MYTable VALUES('Second','''08:00-22:00''');
SELECT 
    ROWName, 
    CAST(SUBSTRING(ROWTime, 2, 5) AS TIME) AS 'Start',
    CAST(SUBSTRING(ROWTime, 8, 5) AS TIME) AS 'End'
FROM
    @MYTable
```

**NOTE:** Code is written in SQL Server 2014 and compatibility level is 130.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the table I'm using has times that end with `24:00`. Since this is not a valid Time, the conversion fails.